# How to access cross-package files in php?

Tags: php

Given the Following structure
[image]

How can InPackageA.php access InPackageB.php and vice versa?

Note:-I am not using composer.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? require_once for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have the class loaded with either an autoloader (like composer) or `require_once` you can use `use`.

**use**

The `use` statement goes right below the `namespace` declaration.

Example:

```
<?php
namespace PackageA;

use PackageB\InPackageB;

class InPackageA {

}
```

Comment: How do i load the class using autoloader?Can you please help?Thanks

Comment: Honestly I don't know as I'm using symfony with composer which handles that for me.